Is there a complex variable proof of $|e^z-1| \ge 1-1/e$ on the unit circle $|z|=1$?

I want to show that on the unit circle $|z|=1$,
$$|e^z-1| \ge 1-1/e$$
that is the LHS has its minimum at $z=-1$.

This could be done using Calculus by parametrizing the circle $z=e^{i\theta}$ and finding the critical points of $|e^{e^{i\theta}}-1|^2$, however this approach is quite cumbersome. Is there a simple complex variables proof of the inequality?

Related: Finding the bounds for $|e^z - 1|$ on unit circle. and Finding a lower bound for $\lvert 1-e^{z} \rvert$ on a circle to compute a complex integral, but no attempt to this one.

There might be a proof starting from $1-e^z = \int_z^0 e^w,dw$.

For anyone with less than 10k reputation, it's remarkable: this question has four deleted answers, each of which were deleted after an error was pointed out. The first of Bowei Tang's links also features four deleted answers, and only one answer left undeleted, which fails to get the 1 - 1/e bound. What is it about this question that invites so many incorrect attempts?

@TheoBendit As it seemed like a simple question, people didn't really think about it.

This would follow from the (stronger) inequality $\left |e^z - \frac{e+1/e}{2} \right | \ge \frac{e-1/e}{2}$, which seems to be true for $|z|=1$.

There are also similar questions such as $$\min_{|z|=1}|\sin z|=\sin1,\quad \min_{|z|=1}|\cos z|=\cos1.$$

The $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ questions can be answered using the product formulas, e.g. $|\sin(z)|=\left|z\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z^2}{(\pi n)^2}\right)\right| \ge |z|\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{|z|^2}{(\pi n)^2}\right) = \sin(|z|)$ for $|z|\le\pi$.

Even more general: $|e^z - \cosh(|z|)| \ge \sin(|z|)$ for all $z \in \Bbb C$.

@187334
Maybe you method can be used to solve $|e^z-1| \ge 1-1/e$.

@MartinR. Did you mean to write $\sinh(|z|)$ in your last comment?

@Pranay: Yes, I meant $|e^z - \cosh(|z|)| \ge \sinh(|z|)$. Plotting the image of circles under the exponential function suggests that this is true.

Why does this simple inequality not work? $|e^z-1| \ge 1-|e^z| =1- e^{\Re(z) } \ge 1-1/e $

@Hunter, the last inequality is incorrect because $\Re(z)=0$ gives a lower bound of $0$.

@Hunter: Because $e^{\Re{z}} \le 1/e$ is wrong.

@Martin if you choose $z=2\pi i$ the inequality $|1-\cosh 2\pi| \ge \sinh 2\pi$ doesn;t hold as it is equivalent to $e^{-2\pi}\ge 1$; more generally if $(2 \cos |z|-1)e^{|z|}+e^{-|z|} > 1$ the inequality cannot hold for the circle of radius $|z|$ as it fails at $i|z|$

@Conrad: You are right, thanks. I had visualized it only for smaller radii $|z|$. I still think that is is true for $|z|=1$.

@Martin I think you are right - in coordinates it becomes the problem of showing that $e^x+e^{-x} - e(2\cos (1-x^2)^{1/2}-1) -1/e \ge 0$ for $0 \le x \le 1$ and the derivative seems to be negative at least as per Wolfram Alpha so the function decreases from $2-(2 \cos 1-1)e-1/e$ to $0$

This is an edited but much more satisfactory (imho) answer that uses just complex analysis to prove the result. The price is that we require a nontrivial theorem in geometric function theory, namely that if $F:\mathbb D \to \mathbb C$ is an univalent holomorphic function with convex image then $\mathcal L(F)=\frac{1}{z}\int_0^zF(u)du$ is also such, so in particular it is univalent. This has been proven by Libera (pdf at the link)
Hence with $F(z)=e^z$ which is clearly univalent in the unit disc and for which $\Re \frac{zF''}{F'}+1 =\Re z +1 >0$ satisfies the convexity condition, it follows that $g(z)=\mathcal L(F)=\frac{e^z-1}{z}$ is convex which is not immediately easy to prove. This immediately implies that $g(\partial \mathbb D)$ intersects the real line in at most two points which are $g(\pm 1)$.
If $h=1/g$ we note that the minimum of $|e^z-1|$ on the unit circle is the maximum of $|h|$ there.
By the Clunie-Jack Lemma (see end solution for a sketch of the proof) this is obtained at a point $z_0$ for which $\frac{z_0h'(z_0)}{h(z_0)} \ge 0$ (in other words the fraction here is a nonnegative real number)
Since $h=1/g$ and $zg'=e^z-g$ one has $\frac{zh'}{h}=-\frac{zg'}{g}=1-\frac{ze^z}{e^z-1}$ hence at a maximum modulus of $h$ on the unit circle one must have $\frac{z_0e^{z_0}}{e^{z_0}-1}=a \le 1$ and writing $w=-z_0$ it follows that $\frac{w}{e^w-1}=a \le 1$. But the discussion above shows that $w$ must also be real so $w =\pm 1$ and $w=1$ is the only one that gives $a \le 1$ so the minimum is indeed attained at $-1=-w$ and we are done!
Note that the Clunie-Jack Lemma follows from writing the Cauchy Riemann in polar coordinates $h(re^{it})=R(r,t)e^{i\psi(r,t)}$ which gives $\frac{z_0h'(z_0)}{h(z_0)}=\frac{r}{R}\frac{\partial R}{\partial r}-\frac{i}{R}\frac{\partial R}{\partial t}$ and at a maximum of $R$ clearly $\frac{\partial R}{\partial t}=0, \frac{\partial R}{\partial r} \ge 0$

First, let us write,
$$
|e^z-1| = |e^{z/2}+1||e^{z/2}-1|.
$$
Now, I want use the fact that the image $C$ of the unit disk under the map $f:z \mapsto e^{az}$ is convex for any $0\le a \le 1$. (This follows from $\Re(\frac{z f''}{f'}+1) = \Re(az)+1 >0$ for all $0\le a \le 1$.) Since $\Re(e^{az})>0$ for all $z$ in the unit disk, the point $-1$ is outside $C$. And, by the symmetry of $C$ about real axis, the shortest distance line segment from $-1$ to $C$ is along the real axis. It follows that the point in $C$ that's closest to $-1$ is $e^{-a}$. Therefore,
$$
|e^{az} + 1| \ge 1+e^{-a} \implies |e^z-1| \ge (1+e^{-1/2})|e^{z/2}-1|.
$$
So, it suffices to prove that
$$
|e^{z/2} - 1| \ge 1-e^{-1/2}.
$$
Repeating this further, it suffices to prove that
$$
|e^{z/2^n}-1| \ge 1-e^{-1/2^n},
$$
for some nonnegative integer $n$.

Update: Thanks to @187334:
Consider $g_n(z) = \frac{e^{z/2^n}-1}{1-e^{-1/2^n}}$. For any fixed $z$, it is easy to see that $g_n(z) \rightarrow z$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Therefore, for any small $\epsilon>0$ and any $z$ on the unit circle, there is an $N$ such that for all $n>N$, we have
$$
|g_n(z)| > (1-\epsilon)|z| = 1-\epsilon.
$$
Combining this with the inequalities $|e^{z/2^n}+1| \ge 1+e^{-1/2^n}$ derived above, we get
$$
|e^z-1| > (1-\epsilon) (1-e^{-1}).
$$
Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we conclude that
$$
|e^z-1| \ge 1-e^{-1},
$$
for any $z$ on the unit circle.

Fix $z$ on the unit circle. Then since $|\frac{e^{az}-1}{1-e^{-a}}| \to |z|=1$ as $a\to0$ you get  $|e^{az}-1| \ge (1-\varepsilon)(1-e^{-a})$ for sufficiently small $a$. In particular, $|e^{z/2^n}-1| \ge (1-\varepsilon)(1-e^{-1/2^n})$ for sufficiently large $n$. Combining this with your inequalities $|e^{z/2^k}+1| \ge 1+e^{-1/2^k}$ for $k=1,\dots,n$ then gives $|e^z-1| \ge (1-\varepsilon)(1-e^{-1})$. Now taking $\varepsilon\to0$ yields the desired inequality.

@187334 Great! Let me update my answer then.

How does one see that $\Re(\frac{zf''(z)}{f'(z)} +1)>0$ implies that the image of the unit disk under $f$ is convex?

@187334 I borrowed that from Conrad's answer (I think there is a typo in that answer). You can also read about it here: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Convex_function_(of_a_complex_variable)

@187334. I replaced the convexity of the image with a much simpler argument.

It looks like you are still relying on convexity when you claim that the image lies in $\Re(w)\ge e^{-a}$, that is, $\Re(e^{az}) \ge e^{-a}$ for $|z|=1$. This inequality is false for example when $a=\pi/2$, $z=i$ and it is not clear how exactly you are getting it from your assumption $0\le a\le 1$.

@187334. Ah yes, you are right! Sorry about that. I’ll roll back to the previous version of the answer.

@ Pranay Why $e^{-a}$ is the point in the image $C$ closest to $-1$? You just konw the image $C$ is in the right half plane (due to $\Re(e^{az})>0$), but there maybe some point in the image $C$ which is more closer that than $e^{-a}$. If you can prove $\Re(e^{az})\geq e^{-a}$, it will be OK( just as your previous version).

@Riemann. This is where the convexity of $C$ is relevant. By the symmetry of $C$ about the real axis, the supporting line (tangent) of $C$ at $e^{-a}$ is precisely the vertical line, so $C$ lies entirely to the right of that line. This is exactly the condition $\Re(e^{az}) \ge e^{-a}$.

@
Pranay
I see, thank you!

Here is a proof of convexity under condition   $\Re(\frac{zf''(z)}{f'(z)} +1)>0$      https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2744339/h-partial-bard-r-is-a-convex-curve-iff-argzarghz-pi-2-is-an-in?noredirect=1

Let $z = a + b\mathrm{i}$. We have $a^2 + b^2 = 1$. We need to prove that
$$\mathrm{e}^{2a} - 2\mathrm{e}^a \cos b + 1 \ge (1 - \mathrm{e}^{-1})^2.$$
Using $\cos b \le 1 - \frac12 b^2 + \frac{1}{24}b^4 = 1 - \frac12(1-a^2) + \frac{1}{24}(1-a^2)^2$, it suffices to prove that, for all $a\in [-1, 1]$
$$F(a) := \mathrm{e}^{2a} - 2\mathrm{e}^a \left(1 - \frac12(1-a^2) + \frac{1}{24}(1-a^2)^2\right) + 1 - (1 - \mathrm{e}^{-1})^2 \ge 0.$$
We have
\begin{align*}
 12\mathrm{e}^{-a}F'(a) &= 24\mathrm{e}^a - a^4 - 4a^3 - 10a^2 - 20a - 13\\
 &= 24\mathrm{e}^{-1}\mathrm{e}^{a+1} - a^4 - 4a^3 - 10a^2 - 20a - 13\\
 &\ge 24\mathrm{e}^{-1}\left(1 + (a + 1) + \frac12(a + 1)^2 + \frac16(a+1)^3\right)\\
 &\qquad - a^4 - 4a^3 - 10a^2 - 20a - 13\\
 &= -a^4 + (4\mathrm{e}^{-1}-4)a^3 + (24\mathrm{e}^{-1}-10)a^2\\
&\qquad + (60\mathrm{e}^{-1}-20)a + 64\mathrm{e}^{-1} - 13\\
 &\ge -1 + (4\mathrm{e}^{-1}-4) + (24\mathrm{e}^{-1}-10) + (60\mathrm{e}^{-1}-20)(-1)\\
&\qquad + 64\mathrm{e}^{-1} - 13\\
 &= 32\mathrm{e}^{-1} - 8\\
 &> 0
\end{align*}
where we use
$\mathrm{e}^x \ge 1 + x + \frac12x^2 + \frac16x^3$ for all $x \ge 0$.
Thus, we have $F'(a) > 0$ on $[-1, 1]$. Also, $F(-1) = 0$. Thus, we have $F(a) \ge 0$ on $[-1, 1]$.
We are done.

"We need to prove that
$\mathrm{e}^{2a} - 2\mathrm{e}^a \cos b + 1 \ge (1 - \mathrm{e}^{-1})^2.$"
But isn't that obvious from  $-1\le \cos(b) \le +1$?
Which leads to  $(\mathrm{e}^{2a} - 2\mathrm{e}^a \cos b + 1)\ge(\mathrm{e}^{2a} - 2\mathrm{e}^a + 1) =(\mathrm{e}^{a} - 1)^2$ which in turn attains its minimum at $a=-1$ which finalizes the short proof.

@Dr.WolfgangHintze I think, if $(\mathrm{e}^{a} - 1)^2 \ge (\mathrm{e}^{-1} - 1)^2$ for all $-1 \le a \le 1$, then your reasoning is correct. By the way, did you see Gary's deleted answer?

You wrote "I think, if (e^a−1)^2 ≥ (1/e−1)^2 for all −1≤a≤1
, then your reasoning is correct."  Sorry, not for all a, but only for those values which correspond to z on the unit circle. Due to b=0 this leaves only the two points a=+1 or a=-1. And a = -1 is the choice for the minimum. QED. Gary has correctly (!) stated the same earlier in a slightly different form. Summarizing, I suggest to reopen his and some other answers given here.

@Dr.WolfgangHintze You wrote "Due to b=0 this leaves only the two points a=+1 or a=-1. And a = -1 is the choice for the minimum". I don't think this is correct to prove $\mathrm{e}^{2a} - 2\mathrm{e}^a \cos b + 1 \ge (1 - \mathrm{e}^{-1})^2$. Denote $f(a,b):=\mathrm{e}^{2a} - 2\mathrm{e}^a \cos b + 1$. You first step is just $f(a, b) \ge f(a, 0)$ with equality if $b=0$. If you only check $b=0, a = \pm 1$, then you just verify that $f(\pm 1, 0) \ge (1 - \mathrm{e}^{-1})^2$.

Yes, and that is all we need, since we are on the unit circle |z|=1.

@Dr.WolfgangHintze I think it is incorrect. $\mathrm{e}^{2a} - 2\mathrm{e}^a \cos b + 1 \ge \mathrm{e}^{2a} - 2\mathrm{e}^a + 1 = (\mathrm{e}^{a} - 1)^2$ and equality occurs when $a = -1, b = 0$; however this does not imply $\mathrm{e}^{2a} - 2\mathrm{e}^a \cos b + 1 \ge (1 - \mathrm{e}^{-1})^2$.

@Dr.WolfgangHintze By the way, I think that the similar mistake happened in Maverick's answer.

Always keep in mind that we are on the unit circle.  BTW we are moving in circles ;-)

@Dr.WolfgangHintze You may post it as your answer.
